# Ajax Image Display from array in Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to show images in a view from data which is in array but everytime it shows nothing to me as error does not appear  in console it directly declare function to be invalid.

```
$.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"{{route('sliders.detail')}}",
      data:{slug:slug, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
      success:function(data){
        var result = data;

        console.log(data);
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
       console.log(obj);
        var array1 =obj.heading1.split(",");
        var array2 =obj.heading2.split(",");
        var arrayLength1=array1.length;
        var arrayLength2=obj.slider_images.slider_pic;
        console.log(arrayLength2);

        var imagedata=obj.slider_images;
        console.log(imagedata);
        var imageLength=imagedata.length;

        if( obj!=''){
          $('#view_info').modal('show');

          $html = '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"><tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th></tr>';
                  for(i=0; i < arrayLength1; i++){ $html += '<tr><td>'+array1[i]+'</td><td>'+array2[i]+'</td></tr>'; } 

          for(k=0;k<imageLength;k++){$html += '<tr><td>'+'<img src="{{asset('public/sliderpic/'.'+imagedata[k].slider_pic+')}}">'+'</td></tr>';}

                  $html +='</table>';

                  $('.info_data').html($html); 

        }

        else{
            $('#view_info').modal('show');
        }

    }
  });
```

[image: JSON response]

Comment: I dont see any images rendering in the table, what exactly you are trying to do? Can you explain it a bit more

Comment: I add this  line but it is  not working'<tr><td>' + <img src='{{ asset('public/sliderpic') }}'+ '/'+ data.slider_images.slider_pic+>'</td></tr>';

Comment: you are getting the images in JSON right

Comment: In my view i successfully showed images  from data but now i also want to show image in view but problem is that i dont know how to do that i am new in ajax

Comment: it is showing me error function is not defined

Comment: can you show the code and console?

Comment: i updated my code and its showing a broken image maybe its  a syntax  error  but unable to find  out

Comment: To help, we need to see your JS error in console.  I suggest you to try setting breakpoints in this funciton, and going step-by-step with F11 or F10. That's how you find the cause yourself.  If you know the number of the failing code line, go set a breakpoint there. Once execution reaches it, hover over variables , trying to find which of them has unexpected value.